# Return a GameObject from a switch statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, switch-statement, return

What is the correct way to return a GameObject from a switch statement? When I try to return avatar I get the error 'use of unassigned local variable 'avatar''. I'm a little mixed up on how to get the return to work with a switch statement. Thanks for the help!

```
private GameObject GetAnimalAvatar(string animal)
{
    GameObject avatar;

    switch (animal)
    {
        case "bear":
            avatar = ForestGameManager.fgm.bearAvatar;
            break;

        case "boar":
            avatar = ForestGameManager.fgm.boarAvatar;
            break;

        case "doe":
            avatar = ForestGameManager.fgm.doeAvatar;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return avatar;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `avatar` variable will not be initialized if none of case conditions is met since it's just declared as  `GameObject avatar;` leading to that error.

You have two options:

**1**.Initialize or set the `avatar` variable to `null` in the default check. This means that if none of the cases condition is met, the `default` one will execute and your case will be set to `null`.

```
switch (animal)
{
    case "bear":
        avatar = ForestGameManager.fgm.bearAvatar;
        break;

    case "boar":
        avatar = ForestGameManager.fgm.boarAvatar;
        break;

    case "doe":
        avatar = ForestGameManager.fgm.doeAvatar;
        break;

    default:
        //INITIALIZED TO NULL
        avatar = null;
        break;
}
```

**2**.Set it to `null` where it is declared:

Change

```
GameObject avatar;
```

to

```
GameObject avatar = null;
```